# jQuery - How to target "First" row "Without" an attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to place a special style on the specific `<h2>` as pictured below:

[image]

This requires being able to target "only the first" parent .views-row div that doesn't have a "style" attribute. I'd love to stick with just CSS, but think I'll have to use jQuery here... but even then, is that possible?

Comment: FYI, you probably got downvoted because you posted the HTML as an image instead of text.

Comment: @Barmar I feel like a better explanation to the downvotes is the lack of actual effort shown on trying to solve the issue and the overall seeming lack of effort put into the question. *(The downvote is not from me, but I can see why would somebody downvote it)*

Comment: You have my downvote, because you did not provide any effort other than asking. You should have at least try it on your own first and let us help you improving your not yet working solution.

Comment: Rather than trying to target the H2 with a funky style rule - it would be better to rewrite all of the above and remove the inline styling - especially since its all the same styling. Then you could add a class to that h2 - or target it in a better way than the first row without inline styling. It is always better to remove the inline styles when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('div.views-row:not([style]):first h2')`.

That will get you **every** `h2` inside the first `.views-row` with no `style` attr.

If you only need the first `h2`, just have to add the `:first` filter like before `$('div.views-row:not([style]):first h2:first')`.

Comment: Alvaro, you just blew me away! This works like a charm! :) Also big thanks to @Barmar for his even more detailed answer. Only selecting this as best answer due to speed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `:not()` modifier along with the `:first` modifier.

```js
$(".views-row:not([style]):first h2").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row" style="background-color: blue;"><h2></h2></div>
<div class="views-row" style="background-color: yellow;"><h2>Div 2</h2></div>
<div class="views-row"><h2>Div 3</h2></div>
<div class="views-row" style="background-color: yellow;"><h2>Div 4</h2></div>
<div class="views-row" style="background-color: blue;"><h2>Div 5</h2></div>
<div class="views-row" style="background-color: yellow;"><h2>Div 6</h2></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this doesn't seem to work. Also, I think I have to do this in jQuery because this situation is within an onclick function.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I appreciate your detailed answer.